# Can Google Protobuf guarantee protocol compatibility between versions of library?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Provided two applications on different platforms use protobuf to serialize data structures in/from UDP datagrams by `SerializeToArray`/`ParseFromArray` use same .proto definitions with line

```
 syntax = "proto2";
```

Should all platform have same version of protobuf library or is there compatibility between  v.2 and v.3?

Variants of platforms:

1. Windows 32-bit applications, statically linked  v.2.5, MSVC 2010 (legacy application)
2. Windows 64-bit applications, statically linked  v.3.2, MSVC 2017
3. Windows 64-bit applications, statically linked  v.2.5, MSVC 2017
4. Linux 64-bit, shared library v.2.4, gcc  4.7 C++11
5. Linux 64-bit, shared library v.2.5, gcc  8.3 C++14
6. Linux 64-bit, shared library v.3.2, gcc  8.3 C++14

PS. Is there any difference between 32bit and 64bit too?

Comment: Protobuf format does not depend on platform, that would be a disaster. But it does depend on version.

Comment: @freakish I need more definitive answer that that. Whenever I repeat that to developers, they say "we place  `syntax = "proto2";`" there. But then we get odd issues with repeated fields and strings. But as I understand that statement form support means actually a version of library. Which is also quite differently working and built depending on arch\compiler. As I once used to support own in-house protobuf library, I know, maintaining  bit and byte order difference, compiler difference and platform difference is a nightmare.

Comment: More likely to be a bug, we'll need a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles could be. Mainly appears on MSVC  + pb 2.5 side interfacing on wire with with MSVC 2017 side.  A `string` if not last in structure "eats" away rest of the message, even while there is no exceptions (with mandatory fields missing), Missing data appears as part of string's buffer. I have working theory that it's do do with fact that modern `std::string` is not zero-terminated (but MSVC one is)

Comment: I think pretty much every implementation of `std::string` is null terminated and is now basically [mandated by the standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)

Comment: @AlanBirtles modifying `.data()` with  a set of chars containing zero byte still yields a  string with a zero in center, afaik. how that even would work with wide char platform, if practically any unicode\wide char string support is dropped from standard?

Comment: Yep, it's always been possible to put nulls in the body of `std::string`, nothing has changed there. Msvc has always worked with nulls (or at least down to VS 2008)

Comment: @AlanBirtles can vouch for MSVC 2.0 there (yeah, I worked with THAT). I tried to dig around generated code, really looks like a bug